# Class convert HashMap in java to NSDictionary in swift

Tags: java, ios, swift

My java code:

```
public final class Status extends HashMap<String, Object> {


    public Status() {
        super();
    }

    public Status(Map map) {
        super(map);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (int) get(Config.KEY_COUNT);
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        put(Config.KEY_COUNT, count);
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return (Boolean) get(Config.KEY_ACTIVE);
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        put(Config.KEY_ACTIVE, active);
    }

    public Object getTypingIndicator() {
        return get(Config.KEY_TYPING);
    }

    public void setTypingIndicator(Object typing) {
        put(Config.KEY_TYPING, typing);
    }

    public String getProfileName() {
        return (String) get(Config.KEY_PROFILE_NAME);
    }

    public void setProfileName(String profileName) {
        put(Config.KEY_PROFILE_NAME, profileName);
    }
}
```

How do I write this in swift? I thought of using `NSDictionary` but am not able to wrap my heard around implementation and usage.

Note: all the config declaration are just strings.

This what I am trying so far:

```
class Status: NSDictionary {
  
  var count: Int? {
    get {
      return self[Config.KEY_COUNT] as? Int
    }
    set {
      self[Config.KEY_COUNT] = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Am I on a right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good so far, although unless there's a specific reason to keep the dictionary-based nature of the class, you really might want to consider something much simpler, like:

```
class Status {
    var count : Int?
    var active : Bool?
    var typingIndicator : Bool?
    var profileName : String?
}
```

It's far quicker, far simpler, and far more legible.